# Не видит сервлет

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Не могу подключиться к тестовому сервлету, что я делаю не так?

Почему не срабатывает паттерн и затем редирект?

Код формы:

```html
<form action="Hello" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
  <input type="submit" value="Добавить запись">
</form>
```

Код сервлета:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Hello", urlPatterns = {"/Hello"})
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/Testcracker/pages/search.jsp");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: action надо не Hello, а /app/Hello  где app - имя вашего веб-приложения

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решена. На его основе написал контроллеры для приложения. Проблема оказалась в отсутствии строчки response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");. Добавив ее в сервлет получил и редиректы, и более сложные решения.
Насчет комментария про action. Прописал url pattern /pages/Hello в xml, а в форме оставил все как есть. Если вдруг понадобится код, то отписывайте.